# 8 Character Device names

Tags: networking

Is there any reason to still use only 8 characters in a device name? My boss still uses this rule for printers, computers, routers, servers... basicly any device connected to our network. This leads to massive confusion among users, especially when it comes to printer. It also leads to confusion from an administration standpoint because every device is named vaguely, and similarly(its only 8 characters!).

I understand the history behind this and compatibility with older systems, but none of our legacy systems will ever make use of PS-printers and Wifi networks. Is there any reason to still do this, and what is everyone else doing when it comes to naming network devices at an enterprise level?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My offhand answer is "No, absolutely not". We ditched that thinking years ago and haven't had a single problem. We're also on the leading edge of things, have minimal legacy tech, and if it breaks because of an upgrade it's both acceptable and fixed proper. *Your situation may be different*.

Comment: Both answers are good but I can only approve one! I made the argument of why would they allow 16 characters if they REALLY only want 8...fell onto deaf ears, but thanks for letting me know how the rest of the world thinks

Answer (score 5):

I've never heard of an 8 character limit for device names but there certainly is a 16 character limit for NetBIOS names. In a Windows environment NetBIOS names are limited to 15 characters.

Comment: I vaguely recall that you could see some weird quirks under WFW/NT 3.5 with overly long names.  But it has been a while since that mattered.